# SQL Join based on a column value

Tags: sql, join, stored-procedures

I want to Join different tables based on column value

if [dbo].[fin_FixedAssetRegister].TransactionType  = 'IOD' then join  [dbo].[sms_IssueOrderDetail]

if [dbo].[fin_FixedAssetRegister].TransactionType  = 'GRND' then join [dbo].[sms_GoodsReceivedNoteDetail]

if [dbo].[fin_FixedAssetRegister].TransactionType  = 'OBL' then join [dbo].[sms_OpeningBalanceSMSDetail]

Comment: I suppose that you want join on  CASE .. END

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would typically use several `left join`s. Your question gives very little information about the underlying structures, but the idea is:

```
select ...
from fin_FixedAssetRegister r 
left join sms_IssueOrderDetail od 
    on od.<???> = r.<???> and r.TransactionType = 'IOD'
left join sms_GoodsReceivedNoteDetail nd 
    on nd.<???> = r.<???> and r.TransactionType = 'GRND'
left join sms_OpeningBalanceSMSDetail bd
    on bd.<???> = r.<???> and r.TransactionType = 'OBL'
```

THe `<???>` represent the names of the columns that are used to join the tables, which you did not provide.